# How to determine a linear classifier using least squares?

Tags: linear-algebra

My task: I have two sets of points which belongs to separate classes (e.g. circles, crosses) in the coordinate system. I must find a linear classifier which divides the plane into two independent parts, where each of them consist of points just of one class. How to accomplish this using least squares method?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining some of your variables, and then consider what the least squares method is doing.

To get you started:

Let $X_i = 1$ if a point $i$ belongs to the circle class and $X_i = 0$ if it belongs to the crosses class.

Edit: Not correct $\Longrightarrow$ Then if you assume $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \epsilon$ ...

I misinterpreted your question at first. Since you have pairs of points $(Y_{1_i},Y_{2_i})$ along with the classifying variable $X_i$, the above equation will not give you what you are looking for.

I believe your problem is better suited for logistic regression, which most commonly uses maximum likelihood to estimate the parameters.

Ordinary Least Squares is not a classifier per se, and probably will not give you the solution you are looking for. Consider the following example.[image]

As you can see, the line of best fit will go through the center of each group, but will not create a line that classifies the coordinate space.

Comment: But, how to determine β0, β1?

Comment: I updated my answer, as I believe it did not properly address the problem.